# Proof in Theorem List of L

Tags: proof-writing

Prove the theorem $\vdash A \rightarrow (\neg B \rightarrow \neg(A \rightarrow B))$

I proved a variety of other theorems in the Theorem List that my university professors created http://mathsci2.appstate.edu/~cookwj/courses/math2510-spring2010/Proofs_in_L.pdf but I never quite understood how to do so. I'm not sure how to go about solving this.

Comment: What axioms do you have?

Comment: @Bram28 I have edited the post to include the link to the theorems and Axioms but here is the link http://mathsci2.appstate.edu/~cookwj/courses/math2510-spring2010/Proofs_in_L.pdf

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Deduction theorem?

Comment: Yes we can use Deduction theorem @Bram28

Comment: I would think a useful lemma would be $\vdash \neg \neg A \to A$ ... L11 on your list ... can you assume that one to already be proven?

Comment: Yes, we can assume that any theorem before L17  is already proven @Bram28

Comment: OK, then See Hint below

Answer (score 0):

$A \implies B \equiv \neg A \lor B$

$\neg (A \implies B) \equiv \neg(\neg A \lor B) \equiv A \land \neg B$

$(\neg B \implies \neg(A \implies B)) \equiv (\neg B \implies (A \land \neg B))$

$(\neg B \implies (A \land \neg B)) \equiv \neg \neg B \lor (A \land \neg B)\equiv B \lor (A \land \neg B)$

$A \implies (B \lor (A\land \neg B)) \equiv \neg A \lor (B \lor (A\land \neg B))$

$\neg A \lor (B \lor (A\land \neg B)) \equiv \neg A \lor ((B \lor A) \land (B \lor \neg B))$

$\equiv (\neg A \lor B \lor A) \land (\neg A \lor B \lor \neg B) \equiv (B \lor \top) \land (\neg A \lor \top) \equiv \top$

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Assuming you have $\vdash \neg \neg A \to A$, you can quickly show that $A, \neg \neg (A \to B) \vdash B$, and then use that with the following instantiation of Axiom 3:

$(\neg \neg (A \to B) \to \neg B) \to ((\neg \neg (A \to B) \to B) \to \neg (A \to B)$

To obtain: $A, \neg B \vdash \neg \neg (A \to B) \to \neg (A \to B)$

And since $\vdash \neg \neg (A \to B) \to \neg \neg (A \to B)$

We can use Axiom 3 again:

$((\neg \neg (A\to B) \to \neg \neg (A \to B)) \to ((\neg \neg (A \to B) \to \neg (A \to B)) \to \neg (A \to B))$

To obtain: $A, \neg B \vdash \neg (A \to B)$

And now it's two applications of D.T. and you're there.